# Dynamic jQuery page issues

Tags: jquery, dynamic

So the following code works to generate my table but as soon as I comment out the 'ABT' stuff, the page draws but none of the event handlers work.

Do I have a silly syntax error? Or am I going about generating this page improperly? Perhaps I am appending things in the wrong order?

I am very new to all web stuff, so any advice on dynamic page generation will also be much appreciated.

The html that goes along with this is very minimal.  Really just has the js and css source links and an empty body.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var title   = 'Page Title';
    var form    = $('<form></form>').attr('id', 'form1');
    var div     = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'hasTable');
    var ABT     = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'ABTHolder');
    var table   = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'CETable');
    var head    = $('<thead></thead>');
    var tbody   = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    var headRow = $('<tr></tr>');   

    document.title = title;

    $('body').append(form);
    form.append(div);
    div.append(table);

    //$('body').append(ABT);
    //ABT.append("<input type='button' id='ABTbtn' value='Activate Bypass Timer'/>").button();

    //Create column headers
    table.append(head);
    head.append(headRow);
    for( var i=0; i < $headers1.length; ++i)
        {
        var r1 = $('<th></th>').addClass('r90');
        var sp = $('<span></span>').text($headers1[i]);
        if(i > 5)
            {
            r1.addClass('borderCell2').attr('id', 'th' + i);
            }
        r1.append(sp);
        headRow.append(r1);
        }

    //Create default row (i.e. alternative way to create column headers)
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>').attr('id', 'tr0');
    table.append(tbody);
    tbody.append(tr);
    for( var i=0; i < $headers2.length; ++i)
        {
        var td = $('<td></td>').addClass('borderCell2').text($headers2[i]);
        if(i < 7)
            {
            td.attr('id', 'th' + i)
            }
        tr.append(td);
        }   

    $allCells = $("td, th");
    $('#CETable tr').addClass("whiteRow");
    $('#CETable tbody td')
    .on("click", function() {
        $cell = $(this);
        populateVars($(this));

        alert( "ID: " + $trow.find("td:first").text() + " , Value: " + $cell.text() + ",  Header: " + $thid.text() );
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
        $cell = $(this);
        populateVars($(this));

        //Highlight Row
        highlightRow($trid);

        //Highligh Column
        highlightColumn($cell)
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $cell = $(this);
        populateVars($(this));

        //Un-highligh row
        unHighlightRow($trid)

        //Un-highlight column
        unHighlightColumn();
    });

//    $('#ABTbtn').on("click", function(){
//      alert('ABT!');
//    });        
});
```

EDIT: I tested it with just appending the ABTHolder div and left the button off and everything works fine. I can click on td's and the ABTHolder div.

How come adding the button breaks it?

Comment: ABT stuff ? Did not get that

Comment: @Andy897 The last few lines of code.

Comment: those are commented out

Comment: //$('body').append(ABT);         
//ABT.append("<input type='button' id='ABTbtn' value='Activate Bypass Timer'/>").button();

Answer (score 0):

You should create first the button, then append it, and then click the button object.

Right now you're just trying to click the ABT object.